# .NET Standard 1.4 Class Library in UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-standard, .net-standard-1.4

I'm exploring the idea of using this product in a UWP app, and one approach I'm starting to look at is to port the available C# .NET wrapper the manufacturer made available on their website to a Class Library using .NET Standard 1.4.

https://www.usdigital.com/products/interfaces/pc/usb/USB4

I believe I've got it close where I can reference the library in my UWP app and it runs, but I keep running into issues like the one below. I've tried referencing NuGet packages for `System.Threading.ThreadPool` (v4.3.0) and `NETStandard.Library` (v1.6.1), but it doesn't work. I have verified that the ported class library still works for an existing .NET desktop app we've used it on.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.ThreadPool,
>   Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Edit1:

I've removed portions of code that reference `System.Threading` and it seems that was the least of my problems. UWP app now runs, however it's unable to read from the device. Verified it still works on the old .NET desktop app with the modification.

The class library has a bunch of `[DllImport("USB4.dll")]`. Is that not supported in .NET Standard 1.4?

Comment: Neither `System.Thrading` nor .Net Standard 1.6 is supported by UWP.

Comment: I am waiting for .Net Standard 2.0 support in UWP

Comment: I left the office for the day, but I'll try adding `<DeviceCapability Name="usb">...</DeviceCapability>` to my appxmanifest tomorrow since the device is connected to USB.

Comment: I just tried this again with the added .NET Standard 2.0 support for UWP, but so far, it still doesn't work for UWP.